# Downloading files

Tags: html

Right now I have `<a href="...">FILE</a>` to allow users to download a file. I don't like that because it forces them to leave the current page and have to reload it (which takes a few seconds) when they want to go back

What is the easiest way to have users download a file?

Comment: Have you tried using javascript?

Comment: @pqsk: How's Javascript going to help here?

Comment: An AJAX popup or an iframe or even flash/silverlight.

Comment: @pqsk: Overkill much? Just configure the webserver properly and the parts of the HTTP protocol that haven't changed in several decades will do all the work. I keep seeing reinventing of the wheel all over the place on the web now and it's a bit disturbing!

Comment: I see where you're coming from. Some people just don't know how to configure a web server (or have access to it). I always go for the fastest solution. putting up a lil javascript is a fast solution. Point taken though. I guess it's on him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have the server send a `Content-Disposition: attachment` header for the resource in question. It'll then be presented to the user (if they have a sane browser) as a file to "save", rather than as a new page.

For certain types of resources this may mean you write a proxy script in PHP, or perhaps you can configure your webserver to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method:

```
<a href="..." target="_blank">FILE</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way to force a download without a server-side solution is to ZIP the file and then link to this archive. Provided that there aren't any limitations on using ZIP files almost every web browser I've encountered will download the file to the user's computer.

If you don't have server-side support, which I am just assuming because you're asking about the HTML and not a scripting language, you cannot always make a file download form the browser. This is because not every web browser is configured the same and the default application on the user's computer may also be set to something you can't predict.

Also, you should use the linking method that @craig1231 suggested so that the file download request is happening in a new window.

```
<a href="..." target="_blank">FILE</a>
```

This will cut down on some of the time needed to refresh pages and, in most cases, when the web browser encounters a ZIP file as the URL of the window it will close the window once the file starts to download.